# Line dividing closed plane figure into congruent parts

Tags: terminology, education, plane-geometry

Today in class a student observed and asked the following:

> While the diagonal of a rectangle is not a line of symmetry, it does cut the rectangle into two congruent parts. This is a noteworthy property. Is there a name for this kind of line segment (one that cuts a closed plane figure into two new congruent closed plane figures)?

This stumped me. It also brought to mind a more general question: Is there a name for a line segment that cuts a closed plane figure into two new closed plane figures with equal area?

Comment: In this case you have a rotational symmetry about the midpoint in the line.

Comment: See works of Besicovitch (https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103044250). Other names are Winternitz, Grunbaum.

Answer (score 1):

A line that cuts a polygon into two congruent polygons does not necessarily correspond to a symmetry of the original polygon.  Consider e.g.

[image]

A line that cuts a plane region into regions of equal area is sometimes called an **area bisector** of the region.

Answer (score 0):

A line of symmetry *including rotational symmitry as Doug M observes above ) always divides a  figure into two symmitrical parts  which will be called congruent figures in case the initial figure was a closed figure.

Is every line which divides thus  a line of symmetry....i leave that question for now